# Dynamically changing form action

Tags: php

I'm trying to change the form action on the fly, but think I'm having a syntax problem, that I just can't figure out.

This works:

```
<?php
echo "<input type='submit' id='answerbutton' name='$buttonname'
value='$buttonvalue' onclick=\"this.form.action='linktogoto.php'\">";
?>
```

This doesn't work:

```
<?php
$variable = "linktogoto.php";
echo "<input type='submit' id='answerbutton' name='$buttonname' 
value='$buttonvalue' onclick=\"this.form.action=$variable\">";
?>
```

I need to eventually change $variable depending on the situation, so need to get this to work.

Comment: I would use concatenation instead of embedding variables into the string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
$variable = "linktogoto.php";
echo "<input type='submit' id='answerbutton' name='$buttonname' 
value='$buttonvalue' onclick=\"this.form.action=$variable\">";
?>
```

Should be:

```
<?php
$variable = "linktogoto.php";
echo "<input type='submit' id='answerbutton' name='$buttonname' 
value='$buttonvalue' onclick=\"this.form.action='$variable'\">";
?>
```

Notice the `'` around `$variable`.

Comment: Thank you so much Matthew!!!!  I can't believe it was such a tiny change. Now I'm unstuck. Very grateful!

Comment: @WandaEmbar you forgot something. If it is the answer, don't forget to select it as the answer or at the least upvote it

Comment: @WandaEmbar I'm very glad I could help! But, DaMaxContent is right, you should select my answer as `the answer` if it helped solve your problem! This will help future users identify the correct solution in the future, and it's always considered a big thanks to the person who answered your question!

Comment: I don't have enough points yet to be able to do that. Sorry. 

Oh, just noticed I can select it as the answer, just can't upvote it.

Comment: @WandaEmbar That's ok, but it looks like you do now! Let me know if it still says you are too low.

Comment: @WandaEmbar Thanks Wanda :)

Comment: It says I need 15 reputation to upvote. Sorry. Very grateful though. It's working like a charm!

Comment: @gavgrif understood, however the first comment from wanda was "Thank you so much...." I'm not saying the answer is right, but that OP believed it was right.

Comment: @gavgrif we (review board members) are also here to be sure the community follows the rules.

Comment: @gavgrif I completely agree that we shouldn't promote bad practices. At the same time, I think it's very important to correct mistakes even if those mistakes are caused by the [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: @gavgrif I think that correcting simple mistakes so that the programmer can continue their project, and continue learning, would in many circumstances be better than turning the simple mistake into a lecture. Any time a new programmer does something that isn't the ***"best"*** way to do something, if we were to then teach them the best way to do something, then we wouldn't have enough time in the day. The learners would be discouraged and still not have a working project, and the teachers wouldn't have any time.